# What's wrong with this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('create_table').style.display='block'">Insert Table</a>
```

The code works perfectly fine in Google Chrome but in Internet Explorer and Firefox it just redirects to a page with the text "block"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [never](http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/313/the-useless-javascript-pseudo-protocol.html) use the `javascript:` pseudoprotocol. Use the `click` event for this. Besides, also watch the quotes.

Here's the correct approach:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('create_table').style.display='block'; return false;">Insert Table</a>
```

Note that I (optionally) returned false here to block the default action.

Answer (score 4):

Your qoutes are wrong:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('create_table').style.display=''block
```

It must be:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('create_table').style.display='block'
```

But you shouldn’t use `javascript:` pseudo-protocol anyway. Better [use JavaScript to only enrich your document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).